# Movie Player goes blank with white screen once the movie is completely played

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayer whose controls have been hidden.
I have custom sliders to move the video, back and forth and controls to control the speed as well.

Now whenever it reaches the end I can see a white screen.
app does not crash but I can't see the video.

I tried debugging and realized that moviPlayer instance is still there, but naturalSize is reported to be zero.

rest everything is there, including the contentURL property.

has the player released the video ?

**UPDATE:**
The bug onbly appears on iOS4 and not on iOS5.
Anyone any idea on what changes have come to movieplayer in the two versions which we might have missed.